# ASP.NET Core 6.0 Identity Password Invalid Character

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, passwords, asp.net-identity, identity

We have problem with random generated password in ASP.NET Core 6.0+. user can not login if some special sign character exist in password, like "[", "]", "&", "<", ">", "/", "" and ...

Rest password method is: UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, NEWPASSWORD)
After rest password, identity did not generate any error, but user can not login with password.

How to find invalid character inside password?
Is there any document of Identity invalid character in password?

UPDATE:

> Do not Sanitize Password before login. Sanitizing the text
> remove all special dangerous character!

Comment: By default, Identity requires that passwords contain an uppercase character, lowercase character, a digit, and a non-alphanumeric character. Passwords must be at least six characters long.You can flexibly change the password priciple by `IdentityOptions.Password`.
Refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0#password  And if you use the invalid character in password to register user, you even cannot register successfully. I think you need share enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you @rena. IdentityOptions.Password and all option is set to default. our problem is, when user use special sign char in password like "<", user can not login, and they get error message "Password is incorrect".

Comment: Its our fault! we Sanitize the password before login! and sanitizing remove special dangerous character!